# How to Remove Rows Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-engine, active-directory

I've tried at least 3 methods listed on this site, and none of them are getting rid of the rows that I don't want. Hoping someone can help get this function to execute.

I want a list of all Active Directory groups and the members within them, but I want to exclude certain groups (badgroup1@domain.org, badgroup2@domain.org) from showing up on the list in Column A.

Members in these groups have different domains than the rest of the directory (member@other.domain.org from badgroup1@domain.org).

There are about 6 of these groups that need to be removed.

```
function listAllGroups() {
  var RatatoskSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var grouprows = \[\];
  var pageToken;

  var page; //THIS IS WHERE I'M INCLUDING ALL GROUPS - HOW DO I EXCLUDE THE BADGROUP1@DOMAIN.ORG GROUP ONLY?
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({ domain: 'domain.org', maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken });
    var groups = page.groups;
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i \< groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups\[i\];
        var grouprow = group.email;
        grouprows.push(grouprow)
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  var rows = \[\];
  var pageToken, page2; //THIS IS WHERE I'M INCLUDING ALL MEMBERS IN GROUPS - HOW DO I EXCLUDE MEMBER@OTHER.DOMAIN.ORG MEMBERS (FROM THE BADGROUP1@DOMAIN.ORG GROUP)?
  for (var j = 0; j \< grouprows.length; j++) {
    do {
      page2 = AdminDirectory.Members.list(grouprows\[j\], { domainName: '@domiain.org', maxResults: 1000, pageToken: pageToken, });
      var members = page2.members;
      if (members) {
        for (var i = 0; i \< members.length; i++) {
          var member = members\[i\];
          var row = \[member.email, grouprows\[j\]\];
          rows.push(row);
        }
      }
      pageToken = page2.nextPageToken;
    } while (pageToken);

    if (rows.length \> 1) {
      var groupData = RatatoskSheet.getSheetByName("Groups");
      var header = \['UserEmail', 'GroupID'\];
      groupData.clear();
      groupData.appendRow(header).setFrozenRows(1);
      groupData.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, header.length).setValues(rows);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding a "remove"

```
for (var i = 0; i \< groups.length; i++) {
  if (groups\[i\].getName() == "badgroup1@domain.org") {
    groups\[i\].remove();
  }
```

like this:

```
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({ domain: 'domain.org', maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken });
    var groups = page.groups;
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i \< groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups\[i\];
        var grouprow = group.email;
        grouprows.push(grouprow)
      }
      for (var i = 0; i \< groups.length; i++) { //adding in an attempt to remove certain groups
        if (groups\[i\].getName() == "badgroup1@domain.org") {//.
          groups\[i\].remove();//.
        }//.
      }
```

and this:

```
function deleteRows() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[1].includes('badgroup1@domain.org')) { 
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
}
```

and this:

```
function deleteRows() {
  varsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  vartextToFind = "badgroup1@domain.org";
  varrowsToDelete = [];
varlastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  varformulas = sheet.getRange("B1:B"+ lastRow).getFormulas();
  for(vari = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    varformula = formulas[i][0];
    varpattern = newRegExp('\\b'+ textToFind + '\\b', 'i');
    if(formula && pattern.test(formula)) {
      rowsToDelete.push(i + 1);
    }
  }
if(rowsToDelete.length> 0) {
    rowsToDelete.reverse().forEach(function(rowIndex) {
      sheet.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    });
  }
}
```

and this (returns a syntax error that is driving me nuts):

```
const keepers = ["goodgroup@domain.org","goodgroup2@domain.org","goodgroup2@domain.org"];
  do {
    page = JSON.parse(AdminDirectory.Groups.list({ domain: 'domain.org', maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken }));
    var groups = page.groups.filter(g => ~keepers.indexOf(g.id))
```

but none of them work and I'm still getting those bad groups???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some that like this?

```
const keepers = ["goodgroup@domain.org","goodgroup2@domain.org","goodgroup2@domain.org"];
  do {
    page = JSON.parse(AdminDirectory.Groups.list({ domain: 'domain.org', maxResults: 100, pageToken: pageToken }));
    var groups = page.groups.filter(g => ~keepers.indexOf(g.id))
```

Comment: Trying this under any phrase gives me a syntax error... Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `~page.groups..filter(grp => ~keepers.indexOf(grp.id) )` page.groups is an array I believe so this should only keep groups that are in keepers array.  But I don't work with AdminDirectory very much so I could be totally wrong.